# Docker container bridged interface to assign IP address

Tags: docker, ip

I have tried to remove the default `docker0` interface, because I would like to assign IP addresses with use of `eth0` and its IP "range".

First I tried to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and define a new interface, with which I can replace default `docker0.`

```
auto br0
    iface br0 inet static
            address 10.1.1.1
            netmask 255.255.255.0
            bridge_ports dummy0
            bridge_stp off
            bridge_fd 0
    docker -d -b br0
```

You can see below one of my container's virtual interface configuration. The new `br0` interface isn't working; containers can't get addresses from its range. By using `docker inspect`, I've found that they have IP addresses like `172.17.0.X`, which are totally useless.

```
vethb9597ff Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5a:b5:0d:20:56:11
          inet6 addr: fe80::58b5:dff:fe20:5611/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:1296 (1.2 KB)
```

So I am looking now for the easiest way to assign IP addresses from `eth0` in bridge mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO (and I'm not a networking expert) your question doesn't make sense. eth0 is the interface for your network card, which will have been assigned an IP by your router or link. You can share this and avoid the overhead of veth and bridges by using the host networking option, but then your containers won't get their own IP address. You have to go through your PCs network card - there's no way of directly connecting a container to the router.

It's unclear exactly what you're hoping to achieve, but I would suggest having a look at networking solutions such as [Weave](http://weave.works/net/) and [Project Calico](http://www.projectcalico.org/). Also Jérôme Petazzoni's [pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework) project may be of interest and help explain what's going on a bit more.

You can control the IP range that the Docker bridge uses by passing the `--fixed-cidr` argument to the Docker daemon e.g. `docker daemon --fixed-cidr=172.17.0.0/24`. I don't think this will do what you want though; other computers on your network won't be able to magically route to those addresses. I think the solution that closest matches your wishes is probably Project Calico.

Comment: So, on a simplified way, with other words: `eth0` has an IP: `172.10.0.1`. I would like to assign also containers addresses form this range, continuous numbering, like this: `172.10.0.2`, `172.10.0.3` ...

Comment: Your router is responsible for that range, so it won't work like you think it will. I think Project Calico does something like what you want.